# Do...while loop to get a random row from DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, do-while

I am trying to have the script pick a row from a table at random, and keep searching if it exists in another table.

The code might explain it better

```
do {
    // get a random row from table A
    $search = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM `a` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');

    // get the id
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search);
    $row_id = $row['id'];

    // check table B to see if the row id exists
    $check = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT `id` FROM `b` WHERE `item` = "' . $row_id . '" LIMIT 1');
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($check);
} while ($result === 1);
```

From my understanding, it should loop until it finds a song which exists in table A, but not B, and then move on, and I can use `$row_id`.

Now this works, but every so often it will return with a row that exists in table B

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND` is performance murder, do not use on large table, but for a small one its ok

Comment: Performing iterated queries is performance murder, try to achieve your desired result with minimal trips to the database.

Comment: A do while, loops one time, then checks the condition and then loops again if it's true.  `$result === 1` means result must be an int, not `true` not `"1"` but `1` and only `1`,  is possible you have duplicate data? this would also fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easier with a `LEFT JOIN` query to find all songs in `a` that don't exist in `b` and then select a random one from that list. Note also that it's always preferable to select the columns you actually want, rather than using `*`. Based on your code, this query should work:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.item = a.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

You can then remove your `do` loop and replace it with this code. Note I've added a check that there is actually a song in `a` which doesn't exist in `b`:

```
$search = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT a.id FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.item = a.id
                              WHERE b.id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
// get the id
$row;
if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search)) {
    echo "No non-matching songs found!"
    $row_id = 0;
}
else {
    $row_id = $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa gotcha. Edited answer - much better now, thanks for your input.

Comment: @mickmackusa it does need to be a `LEFT JOIN`, `JOIN` will return only songs in `a` that do exist in `b`, which is not what OP wants.

Comment: Guess I'd better reread the question.  Yes, you are right.  I misinterpreted the logic.  I'm deleting my comments (as I do).

Answer (score 2):

Why not run one query instead, which fetches a random row from table `a` that does not exist in table `b`? Generally, a query inside a loop is a bad idea and can often be avoided. Might not be the most efficient query out there, but this should work better than having to loop through multiple queries.

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a 
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.item FROM b)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Then run the query as you would normally, and fetch the single row that it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your bug is, your code looks good. I think the data in your tables may be the problem.

However, instead of looping, you should try doing it in one query. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `a`
LEFT JOIN `b` ON `a`.`id` = `b`.`item`
WHERE `b`.`item` = NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```